# How to write this Python excerpt

Tags: python

Write a Python excerpt that gathers together words into no more than width character lines. You may assume words is a list of words, in order, to be output and width is the maximum number of characters a line may have. Print each line just when you can't add another word to the line without exceeding the character limit for a line.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I think this is *your* homework, not mine.

Comment: [google](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) is your friend.

Comment: (For the people spending effort trying to explain this: someone who pastes a homework question verbatim into SO just wants you to do his homework for him.  He probably was already given a detailed explanation during class, since that's what classes are for.)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) module.

```
import textwrap

words = 'some words to print out'
width = 10

for line in textwrap.wrap(words, width):
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's assume you have a string like this:

```
string = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
```

It's long so there's something to go on. Let's call the width w.

Since you're going on words, you would want to split the string on the whitespace character ' '. This would give you a list of words.

You want to check the length of each word in the list against the number of possible letters left in the line. So if your width was 30, and you print 'the', your amount left is 27. If you can subtract the word length from the number of remaining characters and still be positive, then print the word. Else, go onto a new line.

Comment: it says the words come in a list, which makes it even easier

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you're basically implementing naïve word-wrap.

This is the crude and inelegant way I'd do it:

1. Create a holding variable which you use to dump a single line's output into.
2. While the length of that variable is less than or equal to the maximum line length, `pop(-1)` the first element out of the list of words, and append it to the placeholder string.
3. When this condition isn't true (test it before popping the element), print the line and start all over again.

I'm not doing it for you, but this is the way *I* would start.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should separate creating line from

```
def wrap(words, maxWidth):
    res = []
    line = []
    cur_len = 0
    for word in words:
        if cur_len + len(word) <= maxWidth:
            line.append(word)
            cur_len += len(word)
        else:
            res.append(line)
            line = [word]
            cur_len = len(word)
    res.append(line)
    return res

words = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split(" ")
print '\n'.join(map(lambda line: ' '.join(line), process(words, 12)))
```

Comment: If he uses this for his answer to a homework answer they're going to assume he's cheating, a little too much help here

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the a for loop and the len() functions, this should take no more than 10 lines of code.
something like

```
for word in wordList:
    if((len(word)+len(currLine))<maxLen):
//more code here that I ain't giving you
```

You should append words that fie(plus a space to currLine. Once you don't have enough space print currLine and set currLine to word. Hope that's enough help, if not talk to your professor.